Can infrastructure for generating a protective artificial magnetic field around a planet also be used to propel nearby spacecraft?
This is an attempt at "...maybe you scientists whizzes can visualize what I'm talking about and explain it better." from this closed question.
If a well-established colony on the Moon or Mars (for example) already has the technology and infrastructure needed to create a protective planet-sized artificial magnetic field, could such infrastructure potentially also be leveraged, on occasion, to create a dynamic and programmable magnetic field useful for accelerating (or decelerating) nearby spacecraft?
Let's assume that the spacecraft are purposefully designed to interact with the magnetic fields produced by the infrastructure on the planetary body.
If it is possible, how might the system work? What rates of acceleration or deceleration might be possible?
Update
I feel the need to constrain this question a little better. Let's assume that the colony has 100 million taxpayers and each contributes, on average, $10,000 2024 equivalent tax dollars to capitalize the infrastructure project. So a total budget of one trillion dollars. Let's also assume that today's high-temperature superconductors become as cheap, in the future, as today's copper wire is. Power costs the same as what it costs on Earth today.
Note: this is not asking about propulsion using static magnetic fields, which was covered in these earlier questions:
Using Earth's magnetic field for an electric propulsion system
Can electrodynamic tether propulsion use the solar magnetic field?

The ability to create a strong planet-sized magnetic field implies an outrageous level of technological capability, and I don't think anyone is seriously proposing it at this time. The examples I can find are much smaller systems, eg. one positioned at the Sun-Mars L1 point, which would not provide a useful field strength at Mars itself, but would usefully deflect the solar wind around the planet. Do you have any examples of the sorts of fields you're thinking of?

Also, I'm particularly annoying by the contrived ridiculous acronym prolioferation engaged upon by the people who devised a magnetohydrodynamic simulation for planetary magnetsospheres and called it "Block-Adaptive-Tree Solar-Wind Roe-Type Upwind Scheme", or BATS-R-US for short. Do they have no shame?

The energy required for the planetary magnetic field implies energy is not an issue, so propulsion using similar magic tech will do fine. But, yes, doing various tricks like varying the planetary field could supply (limited) propulsion.

@JonCuster honestly, if neither energy nor scale are an issue then they could probably build anything, being a sort of scifi superpower. At that point it becomes slightly silly to speculate on what they could do, cos it all falls under Clarke's third law.

I’m picturing magnetic field surfing competitions for fun.

@JonCuster a magnetic field strong enough to hold you up risks being a little brain scrambling.

If it’s just some propulsion up in orbit, not so much.

A magnetic field rotating with the planet would propel in one direction and slow in the other, but landing without crashing on that planet would become impossible.
